# Serenity BDD framework test case fails after Chrome Version update 121 ,Could not instantiate new WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Error--
Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 121.0.6167.184

Using serenity <serenity.version>3.2.1</serenity.version>
io.github.bonigarcia
webdrivermanager
5.5.0
Any solutions ?